# approach to the Lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis

I'm going to prove the Lipschitz condition theorem

$$|f(x) - f(y) | <= M|x-y|$$

if this is true with positive constant M, this function is uniform continuous.

which way do i should approach this .

1. assume this is not uniformly continuous
2. start this is uniformly continuous and above equation is true
3. or either way is ok

I guess the definition of the uniform continuous is 
$\delta$   must   depend only on $\epsilon $

therefore, if we choose    $\epsilon \leq  \delta/M$ is this ok?

Comment: Think about the definition of a uniformly continuous function. What do you need to prove?

Comment: the choice of $\delta/M$ for $\epsilon$ is precisely what you want, since it isn't dependent upon the individual points $x,y$ you've chosen, that particular choice works for all $x,y$ and hence your function is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Let's show that $f$ is uniformly continuous using the definition.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and we look for $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whatever $|x-y|<\delta \quad(*)$

and since we have
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|<M\delta$$
so we see that $(*)$ is satisfyed if we choose $\delta=\epsilon/M$.

Comment: Sami, this does solve the problem, but do you think you could explain the reasoning behind the choice? I feel this is what the OP needs most.

Comment: @Marc I edited my answer and this's a complete answer.

Comment: Have a great time my friend, Sami. :)